# number of solutions eqauation on supersingular elliptic curve

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

To [Frobenius endomorphism on supersingular elliptic curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384699/frobenius-endomorphism-on-supersingular-elliptic-curve)

I want to prove that equation $\pi_q(X) = A$ has 1 solution for any point 
$A \in E(\bar{\mathbb{F}_q}))$ where $E$ is supersingular.

Is it true? Is there any way to prove it?

Comment: Aren’t you just talking about a one-to-one self-map on a finite set?

Comment: I want to prove that for any function $f$, $f \circ \pi_q$ may be write as funcion $h$ with deg($h$) = deg($f$). So if $\pi_q(X) = A$ has 1 solution then it is simple to write divizor $h$